# How to propagate colors from bash script to CI (GitHub Actions, Travis, Gitlab...)?

Tags: php, bash, colors, continuous-integration

I'm using GitHub Actions in CI. When I run commands directly in YAML recipe:

```yaml
- run: composer install --ansi
```

the output **is colored**:

[image]

But then when I run the same command inside a bash script:

```yaml
- run: sh composer-install.sh
```

```sh
# composer-install.sh

composer install --ansi
```

It's **without colors**:

[image]

How can I **propagate the colors through bash script to the CI output**?

Comment: Hi Tomáš! Is this issue specifically related to Github actions or does the bash script ignore the color output on the commandline as well?

Comment: Try `export TERM=xterm-color` in the shell before running the command.  To see other possible values for TERM run `toe -a | less`.

Comment: Hi @PtrTon, I think I had similar issue in Travis and GitLab took, but I haven't used them last 2 years to verify

Comment: @KenJackson Hi Ken, I'll try it, thanks. Do you mean in a pi `export TERM=xterm-color && ...` or on a standalone line?

Comment: @PtrTon I've updated the title, so it's more clear it's not really about GitHub Actions to avoid more false positive downvotes. Thanks for feedback

Comment: Execute it in bash, in the terminal.  It has nothing to do with the app you're running.

Comment: @KenJackson I had to add --ansi to the commands in bash, but it works! Thank you
https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/pull/5780/checks?check_run_id=2116971828

Could you create a standalone answer from it so it can be accepted? I know few friends who struggled similar problem and would love to share your answer

Comment: Where are you putting `--ansi`?  Is it a switch for your application?  I'm not familiar with it, so I don't want to talk about something I'm unfamiliar with.  My comment was just for the shell.

Comment: To the script I run in the bash script.https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/1384249d426794ffaf2f9e3360860eaa8f6f87b6/build/downgrade-rector.sh#L35

It's PHP specific, you can skip that part. I put it into comment, just in case any PHP dev will go through this and would miss 2nd piece of puzzle.

Comment: @KenJackson Hi, do you plan to write the answer or should I make one? Just so we can mark this question as answered and make it more useful to other who find it.

Comment: You go ahead, @TomášVotruba.

Comment: `sh` is shell, not bash. You can also try out `bash composer-install.sh` to run bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable colors, include this line in the bash script file:

```sh
export TERM=xterm-color
```

Cherry pick of [@KenJackson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060774/ken-jackson) comment.